# Does the chipset also determines installablility of 32bit OS or 64bit OS?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have Fujitsu Lifebook A6025 with Pentium T2130 and Intel® 945GM/ ICH7-M chipset according to the spec. I want to upgrade the CPU to Intel Core 2 Duo Mobile T7400(Socket M) CPU.  The T2130 CPU supports only 32bit OS, but the T7400 supports 64bit OS.  If I upgrade the CPU to T7400, can I install 64bit Linux OS on it without regard to the 945GM chipset?  I have only 4GB RAM.  Thank you.

Comment: Failing to see what this has to do with software design. Did you mean to post on SuperUser.SE?

Comment: Never mind​​​​​

Comment: *"I want to upgrade the CPU to Intel Core 2 Duo..."* - you probably can't.  Components with laptops are often soldered onto the board. Modern netbooks are even soldering the storage device (SSDs and other non-volatile storage). It saves space and money for the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 64bit CPU, you can use a 64bit Operating System. The chipset is irrelevant.

Comment: Would that it was irrelevant...